# Telerik MVC Grid client .dataBind() throwing exception

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

When I try and call [.dataBind()](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#dataBind) on a Telerik Grid object in javascript, it throws an exception. The same code I'm using was working just fine with a previous version of the Telerik controls (2010.2.930) but since the update (using NuGet) to the latest version (2011.2.712), the code has broken.

These are the various errors on different browsers.

**Firefox 6:** this.dataSource is undefined (telerik.grid.min.js - line 1)
**Chrome 13:** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'success' of undefined (telerik.grid.min.js:1)
**IE 9:** SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'success': object is null or undefined (telerik.grid.min.js, line 1 character 25697)

I have managed to create a very simple repo, all you need to do is put this in a fresh page:

```
<div>
    @(Html.Telerik().Grid(new List<GridData>())
        .Name("TestGrid")
        .Columns(column =>
        {
            column.Bound(e => e.Name).Title("Name").Width("9em");
            column.Bound(e => e.Description).Title("Description").Width("9em");
        }))
</div>
<p>
    <a id="getData" href="#">Bind Data</a>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#getData').click(bindGridData);
        });
    })(jQuery);

    var bindGridData = function() {
        var grid = $("#TestGrid").data("tGrid");

        var testData = [
            { Name: "Name 1", Description: "Description 1" },
            { Name: "Name 2", Description: "Description 2" }
        ];

        grid.dataBind(testData);
    };
</script>
```

The GridData class is just a simple POCO with Name and Description string properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was a bug in their code. I issued a support ticket with Telerik and they gave me  a hotfix.

Unfortunately I can't link to it because it's a private message. BUT, don't fear, I did manage to find a link to it on a public forum page:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/general/gridroutevalues-allowhtml.aspx

If that doesn't work you can always wait until it's fixed in the next NuGet drop.